# Operator NOT IN with Peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

The documentation shows [here](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#filtering-records) how to use the `IN` operator, but I couldn't find how to use the `NOT IN` operator.

If I put a `not <<` I get a syntax error.

If I put a `not <FieldName> <<` there is a `WHERE False` instead of a subquery like `WHERE (<FieldName> NOT IN (SELECT ...`.

Here is the output with the documentation examples. The first one is correct, the second and third are wrong.

```
>>> Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user << a_users).sql()
('SELECT t1."id", t1."user_id", t1."message", t1."created_date", t1."is_published" FROM "tweet" AS t1 WHERE (t1."user_id" IN (SELECT t2."id" FROM "user" AS t2 WHERE (Lower(Substr(t2."username", ?, ?)) = ?)))', [1, 1, 'a'])
>>> Tweet.select().where(not Tweet.user << a_users).sql()
('SELECT t1."id", t1."user_id", t1."message", t1."created_date", t1."is_published" FROM "tweet" AS t1 WHERE ?', [False])
>>> Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user not << a_users).sql()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `not in` is literally a single operator named `not in`, it doesn't mean you can put `not` before any other operator. The fact that Peewee reinterprets `<<` to mean a SQL `IN` doesn't mean it can change Python syntax.

Comment: @abarnert I know... hence my question

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Simple:

```
Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user.not_in(a_users))
```

For slightly different semantics (NOT (x in y)) as opposed to (x NOT IN y):

```
Tweet.select().where(~(Tweet.user << a_users))
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, `~` is overrideable and doesn't need to return a Boolean. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere though.

Comment: Kindall, can you kindly update or remove you answer? It is not correct and may cause confusion to other readers.

Comment: Is there an `exists` operator? I find it weird that you support window functions but not `not` and `exists`

Comment: `fn.EXISTS()` is how you would accomplish that.

Comment: You cannot override `not` and `in` because the Python interpreter coerces the return value to a boolean. Obviously I would have preferred to do it that way.

Comment: I did think I would need an unary negation operator, and I tried `!`. I didn't think of `~`. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a "necro-posting", but this question is first hit in Google for `peewee not in` query, so I would like to add it here:

You can also use `not_in` method which is described in the doc:

```
Tweet.select().where(Tweet.user.not_in(a_users))
```

As for me, it looks much more readable than `~ ... <<` construct.

Comment: Hey, thanks for mentioning this! I've updated my answer to include your edits so hopefully more folks will see it.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Peewee, really. Peewee is using some Python operators for its own purposes. `<<` is a numeric operator normally, and it doesn't make any sense to take its logical negation. Thus `not <<` is never valid Python syntax.

Your second example is close, but `not` applies only to `Tweet.user` (`not` having higher precedence than `<<`). Add some parentheses and you get:

```
Tweet.select().where(not (Tweet.user << a_users)).sql()
```

**Now this still isn't right**, as you've discovered (readers: see the comments for some discussion on this). `not` returns a Boolean value, which is not what is wanted and won't work. Peewee repurposes the `~` operator for this; take a look at @coleifer's answer.

Comment: In case you're wondering _why_ Peewee would use `<<` instead of just using `in` (in which case you could use `not in` here); the `in` operator has to return a `bool`, not a query object or anything else. (What happens if it doesn't return a `bool` depends on your Python implementation and version; it may be an error, or it may get converted to `bool`, but either way, it's not very useful…)

Comment: I don't understand your answer. The way I understand it, those operators are used by Peewee to create an SQL command, they are not interpreted by Python. Infact if you try your expression you get a `... WHERE False`, as in my second case without the parenthesis.

Comment: They can't *not* be interpreted by Python. Peewee provides special Python objects that override operators such as `<<` to construct a SQL query. In other words, there is nothing in Peewee that ever sees `Tweet.user << a_users` and does something with it, that's all done by methods on `Tweet.user`. The result is a kind of domain-specific language (DSL) that works seamlessly with Python because it *is* Python. Unfortunately, I guessed wrong about a solution to your problem.

Comment: Looking at [Query operators](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators) in the Peewee docs, it doesn't seem to support `not`, or `~`, or a method or function named `not_` or `unary_not`… that can't be true, can it? Well, if it is, [Adding user-defined operators](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#adding-user-defined-operators) shows how you can do it.

Comment: @stenci: Also, I'd file a bug against Peewee pointing out that either it has no way to write `NOT` queries, or (if it does) that it's too hard to figure out what that way is from the docs…